Uniqueness of optimal control in infinite horizon LQR
Consider the following discrete finite horizon LQR problem with dynamics
$$
x_{t+1} = Ax_t + B u_t$$
and cost matrices $Q$ and $R$.  The goal is to find a linear control $K$ which optimizes
\begin{align*}
\max_{K} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} & \sum_{t} x_t^\top Q x_t + u_t^\top R u_t \\
x_{t+1} & = A x_u + Bu_t \\
u_t & = K x_t.
\end{align*}
It is known that an optimal control $K$ exists so long as $(A,B)$ are stabilizable.  Moreover, it is defined via:
$$
K = -(R+B^\top PB)^{-1} B^\top P A
$$
and $P$ is the solution to the discrete algebraic Riccati equation.
What are the conditions under which the optimal control $K$ is unique?  My understanding is that the optimal control is unique whenever $(A,B)$ are stabilizable and $Q,R$ are positive definite, but am struggling to find a reference textbook which discusses uniqueness of the solutions.  I imagine this is related to conditions for uniqueness of the solution to the discrete Riccati equation?
